# Animation while playing media with ExoPlayer

Tags: animation, media, exoplayer, animationdrawable, split-screen

so im trying to make a video player that plays media on a fraction of the screen while the remaining fraction of the screen shows different images. I am trying to tackle this using animation list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list android:id="@+id/sequence"
    android:oneshot="false"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/folder_icon" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/play_icon" android:duration="200" />

</animation-list>
```

I was able to set the layout so that I can see a single image and the exoplayer view, but im not being able to play the animation. Im not sure where (and how) should I put the command
`animation.start()`
and where  should I declare the variable
`sequenceanimation: AnimationDrawable`

I´ve tried declaring the variable as a companion object and as a private lateinit var in my activity. Also I tried setting the animation.start() command in onCreate but it's not working.
When I try something along the lines, it messes up my entire code, it stops showing you the list of videos in your local storage and it jumps directly to the exoplayer/animation activity without working.

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know if someone is having the same problem but I was able to solve it by placing the line `animation.start()` on `onStart`.

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    val rocketImage = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.animacion).apply {
        setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.prueba_animacion)
        secuenciaAnimation = background as AnimationDrawable
    }
    secuenciaAnimation.start()
}
```